# creating list with multiple regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a information in the format - 
AAMOD, Robert Kevin; Salt Lake, '91; Sales Associate, Xyz, UT; r: 101 Williams Ave, Salt Lake City, UT 84105, cell: (xxx) xxx- xxxx, abc@yahoo.com.
I am trying to convert the information to CSV.

I have converted the information to a list by splitting with respect to ';' and now for each item of the list, I am using regex to convert it to another list holding only required information and in particular sequence and none if that information is not present.

---

```
    for item in list_1:

        direct = []
        if re.search(r'([A-Z]{3,}),([\d\w\s.]+)', item):
            match = re.search(r'([A-Z]{3,}),([\d\w\s.]+)', item)
            direct.append(match.group(1))
            direct.append(match.group(2))

            break

        else:
            match1 = re.search(r'\'(\d+)', item)
            if match1:
                direct.append(match1.group(1))
                break                                        
            else:
                 match2 = re.search(r'(r:[\w\d\s.]*,*\s*([\w]*)\s*([A-Z]{2})\s([\d]{5}),\s*(.\d{3}.\s\d{3}-\d{4}),\s*(\w+[\w\d\s.]+@+\s*[\w\d.]+\.+\w+))', item)
                 if match2:
                      direct.append(match2.group(2))
                      direct.append(match2.group(3))
                      direct.append(match2.group(4))
                      direct.append(match2.group(5))
                      direct.append(match2.group(6))
                      break
                  else:
                      direct.append('')
                      break

     print direct
```

---

when I run this code, list only shows first match. 
And if I run each re.search operation individually, it is working. But the moment I try to combine them using nested if-else, nothing happens.  So can anyone suggest where is the logic wrong?

---

Expected output:
[AAMOD, Robert Kevin, 91, Sales Associate, Salt Lake City, UT, 84105, (xxx) xxx- xxxx, abc@yahoo.com]

Comment: Look, I got something - http://ideone.com/8u63R3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is working for first name and last name but this code unable to append other information to the list

Comment: You wrote: *when I run this code, nothing happens*. I showed that something does happen. Now, you have that `item`, right? What is the expected output? What was the *purpose* of those `if`s? Are those parts *optional*?

Comment: [AAMOD, Robert Kevin, 91, Sales Associate, Salt Lake City, UT, 84105, (xxx) xxx- xxxx, abc@yahoo.com]
This is my expected result. unwanted information has been deleted and each value is comma seperated

Comment: That is it, I could not match the string correctly because the digits were replaced with `x` (which is not a digit). I suggest using optional groups.  Check http://ideone.com/4aN9oH

Comment: Same regex, another way: http://ideone.com/nGpNPE

Comment: And the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aD1zN0/1).  The VERBOSE flag must be used and subpatterns must be explained to keep it maintainable. Best regards.

Comment: @P_S You need to test out each block of code under if/else and use a strategy to narrow down which regex is not working. Its kind of an elimination game and then you will have an aha! moment. You can test out your python regexes here: http://pythex.org/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So you are suggesting to try regex on whole expression at once rather than breaking it and then matching. Thanks, I will try this and will verbose flag too.

Comment: If it works for all the test cases let me know so I could add an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is working perfect with the given example but if one particular information is missing then everything messed up. But I am able to find the bug in my code. I have to declare list before the loop. Thanks for all the help. I appreciate it :)